# Как присвоить тегу атрибут в puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

Как присвоить тегу input атрибут в puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

Если элемент ещё не получен как ElementHandle, тогда можно так:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('selector').setAttribute('name', 'value');
});
```

Если уже есть ElementHandle, можно так:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('selector');
// ...
await elementHandle.((element) => {
  element.setAttribute('name', 'value');
});
```

Comment: а как подключить ElementHandle?

Comment: Во втором примере первая строчка как раз его получает. В документации все функции, которые его возвращают, соответственно обозначены (см. их return).