# Как подключить ElementHandle?

Tags: puppeteer

Как подключить ElementHandle?
puppeteer

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194132/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%b2-puppeteer#comment2083350_1194201

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как присвоить тегу атрибут в puppeteer?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194132/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%b2-puppeteer)